# How to create a custom RTE plugin for pathfield or pathbrowser

Tags: javascript, plugins, aem, aem-6, rte

I want to create a custom RTE plugin which will be having one field with browse option and cancel and OK button.
Do we have any working example on this.

I tried creating the plugin with editorKernel but I am able to create only textfield. I am struggling to get the browse button.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please share the config and code that you tried or any errors in the browser or in the AEM logs that could give us a hint of the potential issue. Thanks.